# How to display images in the uiwebview

Tags: cocoa-touch, image, uiwebview

I am implementing a UIWebView. In that I just need to display an iamges. But I am not able to do it. Please check out my code, and please let me know does I make any mistake.

```
NSString *absStirng=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL] absoluteString];
 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:@"<html>"];
 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:@"<body>"];
 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:@"<a href='/#/'><img src="];
 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:absStirng];
 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:@"image.png /></a>"];
 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:@"</body>"];
 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:@"</html>"];
 [myWebView loadHTMLString:appendString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://serverUrl/"];
```

Please help me out of this, I am trying it from two days..
Thank you,
Madan Mohan.

Comment: You would benefit from using https://github.com/karelia/KSHTMLWriter rather than building the HTML yourself like this.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading from "returnString", instead of "appendString". If absStirng is your image url, no need to put image.png in addition. And I think you should put the image url in quotes when creating the html.

You would also benefit by using a mutable string.

Comment: Sorry, But its not a problem.