# Images not loading in UIWebView

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiwebview

I am implementing a UIWebView. In that I just need to display two images.One is coming from the server path and one is local.If I point the baseURL to server the server image is loading if I change it to Bundle url it is only loading local image. I don't know what is wrong exactly. Please check out my code, and please let me know does I make any mistake.

```
 NSString *absStirng=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL] absoluteString];
 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:@"<html>"];
 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:@"<body>"];
 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:@"<a href='/#/'><img src="];
 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:absStirng];
 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:@"image.png /></a>"];
 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:@"<a href='/#/'><img src="];
 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:@"image.png /></a>"];
 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:@"</body>"];

 appendString =[appendString stringByAppendingString:@"</html>"];
 [myWebView loadHTMLString:returnString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://serverUrl/"];
```

Comment: exact duplicate of [How to display images in the uiwebview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601711/how-to-display-images-in-the-uiwebview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass full URL path for remote image.